# Turn function into toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
togglescroll()
$(".icon").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(100);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
    $('#container').foggy({
       blurRadius: 10,          // In pixels.
       opacity: 0.8,           // Falls back to a filter for IE.
       cssFilterSupport: true  // Use "-webkit-filter" where available.
     });
});
});
```

However, I'd like the function `foggy` to also be a toggle so that when `.icon` is clicked again the function is disabled. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#container').toggleClass('active').foggy(false);` to remove foggy. Add and toggle a class to see if plugin active or not.

> You need to do `addClass('active')` if you are initializing foggy somewhere else.

```
function togglescroll(){
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(100);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
    if($('#container').hasClass('active')){
        $('#container').toggleClass('active').foggy(false);
    } else {
        $('#container').toggleClass('active').foggy({
           blurRadius: 10,          // In pixels.
           opacity: 0.8,           // Falls back to a filter for IE.
           cssFilterSupport: true  // Use "-webkit-filter" where available.
        });
    }
}
```